# Counting total values of lengths of variables in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list that that can contain a maximum of 4 variables. What I would like to achieve is to combine all combinations of the below stepping through them to work out what the total length of the list would be for each combination. I'd like to write the combination together with the length. Each variable below can only appear once in the list however a variable called "James" can appear more than once. The variables are:

- James (can appear more than once)
- Pauline (can only appear once)
- Sarah (can only appear once)
- Benedict (can only appear once)
- Phillippa (can only appear once)
- John (can only appear once)

So, I'd like to loop through adding the variables to my list, calculating length and then doing it again but with the next combination.

I am happy to how to generate `(len(my_list)` but I'm just wondering what is the best method to step through generating the different combinations? So it would be as below for a start:-

```
my_list = ['James', 'James', 'James', 'James']
my_list = ['Pauline', 'James', 'James', 'James']
......
my_list = ['John', 'Sarah', 'Benedict', 'Phillippa']
```

I'm just unsure how to iterate through the 6 names and create all possible combinations to populate the list.

I'm not looking for the solution but more how to perform this iteration function if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is setup for `itertools`, e.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it

n = 4
choices = ['James']*n + ['Pauline', 'Sarah', 'Benedict', 'Phillippa', 'John']
list(it.combinations(choices, r=n))

Out[]:
[('James', 'James', 'James', 'James'),
 ('James', 'James', 'James', 'Pauline'),
 ('James', 'James', 'James', 'Sarah'),
 ('James', 'James', 'James', 'Benedict'),
 ...
 ('Pauline', 'Sarah', 'Benedict', 'John'),
 ('Pauline', 'Sarah', 'Phillippa', 'John'),
 ('Pauline', 'Benedict', 'Phillippa', 'John'),
 ('Sarah', 'Benedict', 'Phillippa', 'John')]
```

But it is hard to tell from your example, you may be looking for `permutations`:

```
In []:
list(it.permutations(choices, r=n))

Out[]:
[('James', 'James', 'James', 'James'),
 ('James', 'James', 'James', 'Pauline'),
 ('James', 'James', 'James', 'Sarah'),
 ('James', 'James', 'James', 'Benedict'),
 ...
 ('James', 'John', 'Benedict', 'James'),
 ('James', 'John', 'Benedict', 'James'),
 ('James', 'John', 'Benedict', 'James'),
 ('James', 'John', 'Benedict', 'Pauline'),
 ...]
```

Comment: Thanks @AChampion. Using Python 2.7, I'm getting a syntax error on 'choices = [*['James']*n,....]

Comment: @thefragileomen why did you tag with both python versions? Are you trying to write code compatible for *both*?